# Eclipse-cdt to index my C++ code only

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, cmake, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to have eclipse index my C++ code (built using cmake)?

I prefer to compile/run the actual code using a bash prompt, but I would like to write code in an editor like eclipse so I can easily follow definitions and have auto-completion.

I'm worried the C++ indexing in eclipse will become out of sync at some point because I'm compiling outside.

Right now the method I'm using is this method:
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

which appears to work, but it seems like this method also causes eclipse to rebuild my project when I import it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I currently use Eclipse as an editor with its index on a project that is built outside of eclipse. Just turn off all the automatic build options in the project, and it will still index the code for you whenever a file changes. My project uses a bunch of special scripts to perform the build, so I just left it as a default c++ project from existing code, using the CDT builder when I created the project.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that eclipse-cdt could index without hooking into the compilation of it.

Comment: it still uses your compiler to do some of the indexing, but it invokes it in a way that doesn't produce any code. It will try to build the code when you first create the project, but then you can disable all the auto builds and it will just do the indexing...